# how to get a estimated arrival time to specipic point in googleMaps API and in waze API?

Tags: waze

how to get a estimated arrival time to specipic point in googleMaps API and in WAZE API?
I'm looking for the realy method in the API of waze and maps.

Comment: This question does not show research effort. If you are having problems please post your current best guess. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)